# Function information display when hovering mouse in Visual Studio 08

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, function, mouse

I am just wondering which one is the format I have to write comments in functions so they display when hovering over the function with the mouse.

something like

```
void myfunct(int a; char b, float c);

This function just messes with the variables with no objective 
but to show people from stack overflow what I mean.
Inputs-> a: does nothing
         b: neither this one
         c: nope
```

So when I use the functions in a big project I don't need to go looking for what was that specific function for or what was that variable's meaning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you think of something like C# or VB that show description of parameters and function, there is no such thing in MSVC, but Microsoft have an special format for code comments as follow that you can use for generating help:

```
/// <summary>
/// summary of variable, function, class or any thing else
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// detailed description of object
/// </remarks>
/// <param name="a">description of a</param>
/// <param name="b">description of b</param>
/// <param name="c">description of c</param>
/// <returns>describe return value of function</returns>
```

when you compile your code it will generate an XML document that can be used to generate help documents.